# Problems with update statement in c#

Tags: c#, t-sql

Im relatively new to programming in C# and i have come across a problem during creating an update statement, i managed to get an insert statement to successfully run however there seems to be an error with the confirmation of the ID, the form basically looks up from a database and displays the information in a datagridview, then once a record is selected the information is displayed into textboxes.

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dbCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Elemental.accdb";


    dbCon.Open();

    string sql = "UPDATE tblOpenCalls SET [CallID]= @callid, [StaffID]= @staffid, [ProblemDesc] = @desc, [ProblemType] = @problemtype, [Department] = @department, [Location] = @location, [Urgency]= @urgency, [DateCreated] = @created, [DateAmend] = @amend, [AllocatedTo] = @allocate,  [Forename] = @forename, [Surname] = @surname WHERE [CallID]= $callid";

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbCon);


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@callid", txt_callid.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffid", txt_staffid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", txt_problemdesc);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problemtype", txt_problemtype);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", txt_department);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", txt_location);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urgency", txt_urgency);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created", txt_created);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amend", txt_amended);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allocate", txt_allocate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forename", txt_forename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txt_surname);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dbCon.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Field Updated", "Update");
}
```

The error that i have got is Syntax error in query expression '[CallID]= $callid'. It is probably something simple i have missed out but thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to put `$callid` instead of `@callid` at the end?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That is the answer, you should post it and get credit.

Comment: This is really a question about SQL, and nothing really to do with C#

Comment: If you put some line breaks in your SQL commands, it will make it easier to see errors at the far ends of the statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have a typo;

```
WHERE [CallID]= $callid
```

should most likely be

```
WHERE [CallID]= @callid
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone, i took your advice and made the changes however i still get the error: Syntax error in query expression '$callid'.

Comment: Are you sure you changed `$callid` **to** `@callid` and not the opposite?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, brief laps in concentration, that gave me the error: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: @user2350399 I've never attempted to use the same parameter twice in a query in TSQL, you may want to try `SET [StaffID]= @staffid, ...` and skip the update of CallID (it's already the correct value according to the WHERE).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, however this still gives the same error, any other suggestions?

Comment: sorry guys, i fixed it, i missed a 'ed' off the field date amended, only took me around 5 hours to realize that!! thanks for the help anyway